# Are there any good tools to figure out the correct gamma corrections for equal appearence?

Tags: color, colorimeter, color-management

Every display device has a different characteristic in regards of how the colours are shown. This can be adjusted by the gamma correction. Are there any good tools that help with finding the right gamma correction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "best" solution is to use a colorimeter to accurately calibrate the screens.

Some screens do have ICC colour profiles that you can obtain from the manufacturer as well, which can give acceptable results.

Answer (score 2):

You want a hardware display calibrator. I have a Huey Pro, I believe. You need to adjust a lot more than the gamma, and it's extremely difficult to do this by eye.